# How do you order a Laravel Builder by its one-to-one relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have two models, Book and Author. Book belongsTo Author (I've trimmed some of the crud from other parts):

```
class Book extends Model {
  protected $table = 'books';
  protected $fillable = ['title'];

  public function author(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Author', 'author');
  }
}

class Author extends Model {
  protected $table = 'authors';
  protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

If I want to get all books ordered by their title, I would use this:

```
Books::with(['author'])->orderBy('title', 'asc')->get();
```

Is it possible to order those books by the author's name? I've tried many combinations:

```
Books::with(['author' => function($query){
  $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
}])->get();

Books::with(['author'])->orderBy('name')->get();

Books::with(['author'])->orderBy('author.name')->get();

Books::with(['author'])->orderBy('authors.name')->get();
```

But none worked. The first, using the with() query, orders all authors before joining them into the books collection, I think. The others threw 500 errors.

If this were plain MySQL, I'd write something like this:

```
select * from books join authors on books.author_id = authors.id order by authors.name asc;
```

Is this possible using Builder/Eloquent in laravel 5.1? Do I need to use a DB query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling **eager load** by calling **with('author')** will load authors in a separate query, that's why author's columns are not available and sorting by them does not work. Explicit join is needed.

In order to sort by a relation you need to join your books with their authors:

```
Book::select('books.*')
->join('authors', 'authors.id', '=', 'books.author_id')
->orderBy('authors.name')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It just works! You can even paginate and use with()! For all the challenges Laravel brings me, like doing simple DB queries, it sure does delight me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

eloquent return a collection its very powerful see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections) for things you can do with that

so to order the books by author name you can do:

```
function orderBooksByAutherName($books){
  return $books->sortBy(function ($book, $key) {
              return $book->author->name;
         });
}
```

---

if you really want to use join the only option is to use the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins)